# 7z "Copy 7zAES" algo brute force with 32 char password for when original file is available (QNAP QLocker ransomware)

Tags: aes, brute-force, ransomware, 7zip

As some in here might know, there is/was a ransomware attack going on worldwide that used 7z to encrypt all files <20MB for a ton of users world wide.

Each user has a unique 32 char password (Upper & lowercase & Numbers - 62 possibilities, no special char where used)

the command line that was being used was a -mx = 0 -sdel -pmFyBIvp55M46kSxxxxxYv4EIhx7rlTD [FOLDER PATH]

(Note: sample password)

Given

- we know the length
- we know the characters used
- we know the plain text

Is it doable to speed up a brute force attack. Or can you explain to me, why the 7z encryption algorithm might be protected against something like this?

e.g. I have this file and I still have the original on backups

Output of **7z l -slt playback.m3u.7z** :

````
1 file, 274 bytes (1 KiB)

Listing archive: playback.m3u.7z

--
Path = playback.m3u.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 274
Headers Size = 146
Method = Copy 7zAES
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

----------
Path = playback.m3u
Size = 122
Packed Size = 128
Modified = 2017-07-13 15:40:12
Attributes = A_ -rwxrwxr-x
CRC = 8CEF1157
Encrypted = +
Method = Copy 7zAES:19
Block = 0```

Looking forward to your responses
Leo
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is not vulnerable to plain text attack.

There are 62 (*you didn't account for special characters but we'll stick with 62*) possibilities for the first character.

There are 62 possibilities for the second character, meaning 62*62 or 62 to the power of 2 combinations (*technically a **permutation***) for the first 2 characters.

Likewise 62 to the power of 3 combinations for the first 3 characters.

Ultimately there are 62 to the power of 32 combinations for all 32 characters, or over 2 x 10 to the 57th power.

There are 3x10 to the 7 seconds in a year. Assuming you test a billion passwords a second that's ... **longer than you can wait**.